# How to recreate tsvector column originally populated by tsvector_update_trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers, tsvector

I'm running Postgres 9.4.

I have a column called main_search_index_col that was populated by this trigger:

```
main_vector_update BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON the_entries 
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE 
   svector_update_trigger('main_search_index_col','pg_catalog.english', 'name', 'location', 'type')
```

I've gone ahead and created a new text search configuration called unaccent_english (public.unaccent_english) to replace pg_catalog.english

I've dropped the above trigger and redone it using public.unaccent_english instead of pg_catalog.english

drop trigger main_vector_update on the_entries;

```
CREATE TRIGGER main_vector_update BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON the_entries
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
tsvector_update_trigger('main_search_index_col','public.unaccent_english', 'name', 'location', 'type');
```

But as I understand it that won't change any of the values in main_search_index_col unless the row is updated or a new row is added.

I instead want to go through and either update main_search_index_col for each row, or drop the column and recreate it completely and populate it as if the trigger in it's new form had always existed.

How do I make the contents of the column main_search_index_col correct for the new trigger?

Also how do I see the exact definition of tsvector_update_trigger?  I have a feeling if I could read the definition of it, it might be helpful in crafting my own solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the definition of `tsvector_update_trigger` in `src/backend/utils/adt/tsvector_op.c`.

You can update the table to match the new trigger definition as follows:

```
UPDATE the_entries
   SET main_search_index_col =
       to_tsvector(
          'public.unaccent_english', name || ' ' || location || ' ' || type
       );
```

But you might as well use the trigger and do it like this:

```
UPDATE the_entries SET name = name;
```

That doesn't require inside knowledge of the trigger function definition, and it will also rewrite the whole table.

After such an `UPDATE` you might want to release the free space on the table with a

```
VACUUM (FULL, ANALYZE) the_entries;
```

**Note:** for recent PostgreSQL versions, a generated column is simpler and better that a column filled by a trigger.

Comment: Your answer is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: I am finding with Postgresql 13 and 14, when I added a tsvector column using pgAdmin 4, it created it as follows:
ALTER TABLE public."Entries"
    ADD COLUMN "SearchVectors" tsvector GENERATED ALWAYS AS (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, (("Body" || ' '::text) || (COALESCE("Subject", ''::character varying))::text))) STORED;
With this, there is no need for a trigger, as this will recompute the column value whenever the indexed field(s) are inserted or updated.